# Ajax Form - get information

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm new to the play framework and I have a question about implementing ajax.
So I have implemented a search page - which has a form on it that sends back a date range.
And it is all working.
But I wanted to get it to work with ajax so I have a few questions.
Do I need to create a new Form Type in the controller? Like I have done previously? Or can I get the data out manually?

So currently in my html i have the following form:

```
<form action="@routes.History.search()" class="pull-right" id="formHistory">
            MinDate: <input id="mindate" name="mindate" class="input-small" type="text">
            MaxDate: <input id="maxdate" name="maxdate" class="input-small" type="text">
            <button class="btn" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
```

and here is my javascript:

```
$('#formHistory').submit( function(evt) {
            $('#errors').show();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url:  jQuery("#formHistory").attr("action"),
                data: jQuery("#formHistory").serialize(),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    alert('History Search');
                    $("tableHistory").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
                    alert(data.id[0].source);
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    $('#errors').shows();
                    alert('History search failed');
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
```

and in my history.java file i need to get the json information out. Previously i have done this by using

```
Form<Login> loginForm = form(Login.class).bindFromRequest();
```

But i do not have an object with min and max date can i just get the json information out manually?

```
public static Result search() {
//So here I would like to get the form information 
}
```

The next question would be how to do this in reverse? Once i have gotten the min and max date, gotten the information out of the database i need to send back a response. Should I send back a json response with a list of the data and how do handle this in javascript? or do I create html on the server and send this as a string and append this in the apporpriate element?
Or the other option i have seen in some demos is creating a view and passing that back and just rendering the smaller view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up leaving it and not using ajax.
But if I was going to use it I would use an ajax request:

```
jsRoutes.controllers.Application.ajaxCommand().ajax({
    data : {
        "var1" : "a",
        "var2" : "b"
    },
    success : function(data) {
        // .. DO something
    },
    error : function(data) {
        // .. DO something
    }
});
```

and use DynamicForm on the server side:
Something like:

```
public static Result ajaxCommand() {
    DynamicForm data = form().bindFromRequest();
    String var1 = data.get("var1");
    String var2 = data.get("var2");
    // .. Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able get data from the form, the same way as you did before sending it as ajax. If you can't get it to work, you can get the data manually with

```
Map<String, String[]> params = request().body().asFormUrlEncoded();
```

As for how you send the data back to the client, both of your suggestions are valid. The easiest approach is to just render a view without <html> and <body> tags, and use jQuery to put the result into an element.

```
success: function(data) {
    $('#myContentDiv').html(data);
}
```

The json approach might give slightly better performance, but is much more complicated to implement. Many people will argument that the html approach is a bad approach because it uses a lot of resouces on the server. This argument might be true for PHP, Ruby on Rails or even Play 1.x, but in play 2 the views are fully compiled, and the rendering process is extremely fast.

If you choose to go for the json approach, I would recommend using something like [knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/).